# Remove single value from vector leaving other occurrences of the same value

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have a large vector of integers in which a single integer can occur in the vector multiple times. I do not know the order of the values within the vector. Consider the code below: I have *vector* and I want to remove a single 1 to get *newVector*. Since the order within the vector is not known outside this example, I cannot simply use *vector[-1]*.

```
vector<-c(1,1,2,2,3)
newVector<-c(1,2,2,3)
```

Some background: I iteratively pick two values from the vector (using *sample*) and then want to remove the values I picked from the vector.

Of course I could loop through the vector until I find the first occurrence of the value I wish to remove and remove it using the index, however, that is very time consuming. All the other results I found end up removing all occurrences of the value, which I don't want.

Comment: Can't you just sample the indices of the vector and use that for (positive and negative) subsetting?

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your comment, that would be a viable option (although it would require some extra coding when changing the indices to pick multiple distinct values; but I hadn't mentioned that in my question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work, as `which.max` returns the index of the first match and then we can remove them using negative subsetting.

```
vector[-which.max(vector == 1)]
#[1] 1 2 2 3
```

---

Also, `match` does the same

```
vector[-match(1, vector)]
#[1] 1 2 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `match`. This finds the first occurrence of the specified value returning its index

```
vector<-c(1,1,2,2,3)
vector[-match(1, vector)]

# [1] 1 2 2 3
```